# how can i align the following panel?

Tags: html, css

Here is the code for my login panel. I want to align it right.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> 
                Log In
            </h3>
        </div>
    <div class="panel-body" >
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uid" name="uid" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log In</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to provide us also the css file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an additional class "right-align" to the parent div

```
<div class="panel panel-default right-align">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> 
                Log In
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" >
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uid" name="uid" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log In</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and add

```
.right-align{
  float: right;
 }
```

in your css file.

or, post the markup including the parent div as well to better understand the issue.

Comment: Bootstrap already has a "pull-right" class that does exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're using Bootstrap. If so, you can add the class "pull-right" or "text-right" to your panel and see if it fits your needs. Also, it's good to remember that the code around your panel might change how these classes will behave. If you provide more details (a fiddle would help), I'll gladly increment on this answer.

You can also check more information on helper classes on this link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes